# What's the proper way of running a mongos client for a sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, sharding

I have a mongodb cluster up and running. I want to setup a client (mongos) to connect to the config servers from ubuntu. Most instructions just say to run this command:

```
mongos --configdb cfg0.example.net:27019,cfg1.example.net:27019,cfg2.example.net:27019
```

Is this command running as a service? Will the process still be running when I exit the shell? What happens if the process goes down? What is the proper way of running this client as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `--fork` or an `init` script to make this run as a service post terminal session shut down.

If the process goes down then your application cannot connect to the sharded set. It will be unable to connect at all to your DB. This is (not the only reason) why you should have good redundancy in `mongos` instances.

I tend to have one `mongos` per app server personally, however, it is all down to preference. Another option is to have a load balanced set of `mongos` instances.

Comment: Do you know any good resources where I can learn how to write an init script in ubuntu?

Comment: @BrianYeh it is a sizeable subject but here is the beginning of it http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html